# React Native 'NAVIGATE' with payload error

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have this screen where it is accessed only if i login successfully, even after login i am getting this error message.
"The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Choose"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Choose'?"

app.routes.tsx

```
export function StackRoutes() {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Choose">
     <Screen name="Choose" component={Choose} />      
     <Screen name="Student" component={Student} />  
     <Screen name="Leave" component={AuthRoutes} />
    </Navigator>
  )
```

auth.routes.tsx

```
export function AuthRoutes() {
  const { Navigator, Screen } = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Login">
      <Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
    </Navigator>
  )
}
```

on the login screen I have the function and trycatch:

```
setLoading(true);
        try {
            const schema = Yup.object().shape({
                username: Yup.string()
                .required('Código é obrigatório'),
                password: Yup.string()
                .required('A senha é obrigatória')
            });

            await schema.validate({username, password});


            await login({username, password});

            navegation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate('Choose'));

auth.routes.tsx

    export function AuthRoutes() {
      const { Navigator, Screen } = createNativeStackNavigator();

      return (
        <Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Login">
          <Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
        </Navigator>
      )
```